# Spring Security with many role

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, express-jwt

I am using spring security(`@EnableWebSecurity`). When I try to authorize with this token on `"/invoice"` or `"/notification"` endpoint I always receive forbidden response but if I don't use `hasRole` attribute or use token with only one role every thing works properly.

Token:

```
{
....
  "exp": 1586366900,
  "iat": 1586348900,
  "authorities": "ROLE_INVOICE,ROLE_NOTIFICATION",
  ....
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class:

```java
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable() //Disabling CSRF
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
                    .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(jwtConfig), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/invoice/**").hasRole("INVOICE")
                    .antMatchers("/notification/**").hasRole("NOTIFICATION")
                    .antMatchers("/test/**")
                    // Any other request must be authenticated
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
```

In my case I want to authenticate with one token on different service. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your authorities must be an array:

```
...
"authorities": ["ROLE_INVOICE", "ROLE_NOTIFICATION],
...
```